# *cdkDragPreview positioning Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Is it possible to change the position when using `*cdkDragPreview` on dragging an item? Right now the styling I did when dragging appears always to the bottom right of the cursor. I would like to place it a the top left.

Any help on getting this in position?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can subscribe to **cdkDragMoved** and offset your ***cdkDragPreview**.

**Example**

following example will offset your preview with 100px in x and y axis

```xml
<div cdkDrag
    [id]="storageNode.barcode"
    [cdkDragData]="storageNode"
    [cdkDragDisabled]="dragDisabled"
    (cdkDragMoved)="onDragMove($event)">
    <div title="Drag this entity and its children"
        class="entity-drag-handle"
        cdkDragHandle>

        {{storageNode.barcode}}
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!dragDisabled">
        drag_indicator
        </mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div
      [id]="storageNode.barcode + 'preview'"
      [ngStyle]="{'background-color': this.getBackgroundColor(0.6)}"
      class="entity-drag-preview"
      *cdkDragPreview>
         <h4>{{storageNode.barcode}}</h4>
         <p>{{formattedDescription}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

keep in mind this uses typescript 3.7 features that won't work on older versions

```typescript
public onDragMove(event: CdkDragMove<StorageEntity>): void {
    const nodeMovePreview = new ElementRef<HTMLElement>(document.getElementById(this.storageNode.barcode + 'preview'));
    const xPos = event.pointerPosition.x - 100;
    const yPos = event.pointerPosition.y - 100;
    if (nodeMovePreview?.nativeElement) {
        nodeMovePreview.nativeElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px, 0)`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For those not yet on TypeScript 3.7, you can replace one line to make it work in TypeScript 3.6 and below, change `if (nodeMovePreview?.nativeElement) {` to `if (nodeMovePreview && nodeMovePreview.nativeElement) {`.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML]

```
<div
    cdkDrag
    (cdkDragReleased)="cdkDragReleased($event, i)"
    (cdkDragDropped)="cdkDragDropped($event)">

 <div class="my-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

 <div class="my-preview" *cdkDragPreview></div>

</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.my-placeholder {
  background-color: #000;
}
.my-preview {
   transform: scale(0.7) translate(-200px, -100px);
}
```

I used translate in .my-preview to place the item upon both x-axis and y-axis, then the scale is used to scale-down to make it look smaller

Answer (score 0):

```
protected onDragMoved(_drag: CdkDragMove<TItem>) {
  const currentTileEl = document.querySelector('.cdk-drag-preview');
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(currentTileEl);
  const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);
  // matrix.f and  matrix.e - position left, top corner
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.